# Hyphenating Noun/Adj + Noun Compounds Before Nouns

Tags: hyphenation

I want to make sure I'm not hyphenating more than I should. Going by Chicago, adjective + noun compounds and noun + noun compounds need to be hyphenated when preceding a noun (but not after a noun). So are these examples correct to hyphenate?

some grizzly-bear fur / the fur of a grizzly bear

a chunk of rainbow-trout meat / the meat of a rainbow trout

a pine-tree forest / a forest of pine trees

a calico-cat face / the face of a calico cat

Venus-flytrap seeds / seeds for growing Venus flytraps

Syrian-hamster behavior / the behavior of Syrian hamsters

the robot-monkey uprising / an uprising of robot monkeys

Comment: All technically correct yet unnecessary. I always ask *Are there flytrap seeds other than Venus?* If not, I'm removing no ambiguity, but making things precious.

Comment: @Yosef Not all unnecessary. The grizzly fur of a bear. Here is some.